# should use GPU?

Tags: c, cuda

how can i know if my serial code will run faster if i used a GPU? i know it depends on a lot of things... ie if the code could be parallalized in an SMID fation and all this stuff... but what considerations should i take into account to be "sure" that i will gain speed? should the algorithm be embarrassingly parallel? therefore i wouldn't bother trying the GPU if parts of the algorithm cannot be parallelized?  should i take into consideration how much memory is required for a sample input?

what are the "specs" of a serial code that would make it  run faster on a GPU? can a complex algorithm gain speed on a GPU?
i don't want to waste time and try to code my algorithm on GPU and i am 100% sure that speed will be gained.... that is my problem....

i think that my algorithm could be parallelized on GPU... would it be worth trying it?

Comment: you could start by telling us what kind of code/algorithm it is and where most of the time is spent (profiling).

Comment: you might also want to accept an answer every once in a while. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon two factors:

1) The speedup of having many cores performing the floating point operations

This is dependent upon the inherent parallelization of the operations you are performing, the number of cores on your GPU, and the differences in clock rates between your CPU and GPU.

2) The overhead of transferring the data back and forth between main memory and GPU memory.

This is mainly dependent upon the "memory bandwidth" of your particular GPU, and is greatly reduced by the Sandy Bridge architecture where the CPU and GPU are on the same die.  With older architectures, some operations such as matrix multiplication where the inner dimensions are small get no improvement.  This is because it takes longer to transfer the inner vectors back and forth across the system bus than it does to dot product the vectors on the CPU.

Unfortunately these two factors are tough to estimate and there is no way to "know" without trying it.  If you currently use BLAS for your SIMD operations, it is fairly simple to substitute in CUBLAS which has the same API except it sends the operations over to the GPU to perform.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for a parallel solution you should typically ask yourself the questions

1. The amount of data you have.
2. The amount of floating point computation you have.
3. How complicated is your algorithm i.e. conditions and branches in the algorithm. Is there any data localization?
4. what kind of speedup is required?
5. Is it Realtime computation or not?
6. Do alternate algorithms exist (but maybe they are not the most efficient serial algorithm)?
7. What kind of sw/hw you have access to.

Depending on the answers you are looking for you may want to use GPGPU, cluster computation or distributed computation or a combination of GPU and cluster/distributed machines.

If you could share the any information on your algorithm and size of data then it would be easier to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Regular C code can be converted to CUDA remarkably easily. If the heavy hitters in your algorithm's profile can be parallelized, try it and see if it helps.

Comment: "remarkably easily" I strongly disagree with you. It is true for very rare and obvious case. Tightly coupled data dependency can make code uncovertable to CUDA.